# Use $or operator in @Query annotation in spring data mongodb repository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using spring-data-mongodb.

I want to use $or operator in my repository.

This is my query:

```
@Query("{'type':?0}")
List<Doc> findByType(String type, Pageable pageable);
```

How do use $or in @Query so as it can match either type or name and fetch me a document.
Please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per MongoDB [reference for $or](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/), your Query should be

```
@Query("{'$or':[ {'type':?0}, {'name':?1} ]}")
```

you'll need to give pass type and name params.

Comment: very useful, works for me thank you @ikumen

Answer (score 4):

I found answer to my question, which also handles optional query parameter in it.

Query should be :

```
@Query("{'type':?0,'$or':[{ $where: '?1 == null' },{'key':?1},{ $where: '?2 == null' },{'username':?2}]}")
    List<Doc> findByType(String type, String key, String username, Pageable pageable);
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't even need a manually defined query for that:

```
Page<Doc> findByTypeOrName(String type, String name, Pageable pageable);
```